# Using target variable to manipulate features

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, missing-data

I often come up with notion when working with machine learning, I think it will be better understood through some examples:

**Example 1**

Say I try to predict a property's price and one of my features is the city identifier. There are 300 different cities in my dataset. My ML algorithm can only handle numerical features, so I decide to transform the field using dummy variables. However 300 columns are too many, therefore I would like to group cities based on something. Should I group them by their average target value (price)? For example expensive cities, average and cheap ones.

**Example 2**

I want to impute missing values using some form of KNN. When trying to define a distance between two records, is it a good idea to include the target variable in the distance calculation? For example if I miss the city identifier for a property, should I fill it with the city of the property with the closest price to it?

**Question**

In general these approaches make sense to me but I can't help but feel that I am introducing some feedback that should not be there. Due to my limited math background I cannot formulate the issue. Perhaps someone else can. Or is the proposed approach flawless?

Comment: I have the same doubt about using dependent variable to impute/transform perdictors. Did you already receive and answer to your question?